# I wanto to make the qunatity of products in a dropdown

Tags: product, quantity, code

My qunatity/Qty on Product page i simple a text field.
I want to change it into a drop-down.

Comment: What will be the numbers in the dropdown?

Comment: the stock of the product

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this my creating/updating your **addtocart.phtml** under your theme with below content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="qty" id="qty" class="input-text qty">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

You can change the quantity as per your requirement.

Comment: tried but no working. Moreover I want to change this in my code module not in my custom theme

Comment: Can you create a select dropdown as mentioned in your addtocart.phtml?

Comment: No I cannot and please give me the correct directory and code to be replaced.